# Nodal Analysis with current and voltage source

Tags: circuit-analysis

Would the following be the correct approach? I am a bit concerned with node C as it introduces another unknown. Do I need to write a constraint for this problem?

$$A:  ((A-Ref)/4000) + ((A-B)/2000) - .002A = 0$$

$$B:  ((B-A)/2000) + ((B-Ref)/2000) + ((B-C)/2000) = 0$$

$$C:  ((C-B)/2000) - I(source) + .002A = 0$$

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Equation C in you system is not solvable because there is no good way to tell what the current of the 12V source is without solving the system first. The beauty of this problem is that voltage at point C is known because the source grantees that point C is held at 12V. This gives you two unknowns A and B and two equations to solve for them.

Answer (score 1):

Since Node C is directly connected to the Voltage source. Hence you can always replace node C with (12 + Ref).

This would make things easier for you. You can also choose Ref to be 0 V to further simplify the math involved.

Comment: How would Node C relate to Node A? Since there is no resistor between them would it only be the .002A as part of the equation?

Comment: The current flowing from Node C to Node A will be 0.002A only.